# Presenting UIActivityViewController with snapshot of a UIView slows down animation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

What I'm trying to do is to create a `UIImage` snapshot of a `UIView` then add it to `UIActivityViewController`. Here's my code:

```
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300, 300);        
    NSArray *dataToShare = @[[view snapshot]];

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                                                                         applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And the snapshot category on `UIView`:

```
- (UIImage *)snapshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, self.window.screen.scale);
   [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return snapshotImage;
}
```

When the `UIActivityViewController` is presented and after selecting a service (Twitter or Faceook for example), the compose view that appears has a really jerky animation, meaning that the view is dimmed, a second later the keyboard appears, then a few seconds later the compose view appears with a stuttering animation. If I remove the snapshot and add a `UIImage` from the bundle the animation works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you tried the same on a `UIViewController` instead of `UIActivityVC` ? Also try : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013842

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What exactly should I try on a `UIViewController`? And what does the AirDrop example has to do with this?

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue. Mine happens when showing the Activity Controller in a UIPopoverController when using Container Containment in the presentingViewController. Don't know if this is relevant.